# Update component when data changes using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So I have a `<NavBar/>` component, and once a person logs in, I want the `<NavBar/>`s login button to change to logout.

What I have "works" in the sense that when I manually refresh the page, you are forwarded to `/` as I have a catch_all route the button does required change to say logout. However, when you do a typical user journey and route through to `/home` after `/login`, the button is not updated.

It is worth to note that the inverse is also true, as if I log in, then refresh the homepage and then click logout. The change doesn't take effect until I reload the page. Only when I reload the page, does the `<NavBar/>` button update.

**routes**

```js
const AppRouter = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const providerValue = useMemo(() => ({user, setUser}), [user, setUser]);
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
  );
   
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <UserContext.Provider value={providerValue}>
          <NavBar {...{loggedIn}}/>
          <Route exact path='/' component={LandingPage} />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/home" component={(routeProps) =>
                <UserApp {...{setLoggedIn, ...routeProps}} />
              } />
          etc...
```

**navbar**

```js
const NavBar = (props) => {
  const {user, setUser} = useContext(UserContext);
  let history = useHistory();

  const handleClick = async(e) => {
    let data = await authService.logout_user();
    setUser(null);
    history.push('/');
  }

  return (
    <header>
      <div className={styles.menuContainer}>
        <h1 className={styles.logo}><Link to='/'>Bookshelf.</Link></h1>
        <nav>
          <ul>
          { props.loggedIn &&
            <li><a onClick={handleClick}>Logout</a></li> ||
            <li><Link to='/login'>Login</Link></li>    
          }
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}
```

I need a way to reload the component or the page. However, if I manually reload the page, the page 404s as I am using the `browserRouter` with a Flask backend. I'm pretty new to React so any advice would be great. I think that maybe `useEffect()` or `history.something` is useful here, but I am not 100% sure on how to handle this.

Thanks!

Comment: try to replace props.loggedIn with  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))

Comment: In the `handleClick` function you're updating the `user` but the links depend on the `loggedIn` prop.